# Android: How to register a passive LocationListener in the Manifest?

Tags: android, gps, locationlistener

i need to receive gps position fixes with adndroid, but i don't want the device to register the LocationListener explicitly in the Activity code or so... i.e. i want to register the LocationListener directly in the Manifest file.

Unfortunately, this does not work :( Here is my code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<receiver android:name=".GPSLocationListener" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

while my listener looks like this:

```
public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "GPSLocationListener.java: GPS LOCATION UPDATE CAUGHT");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
}
```

but no matter what i do, i dont geht the emulator to catch the new (mock) location i push via DDMS... :(

anyone knows how to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at a [Deep Dive into Location](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html). Reto Meier explains how to register a service as the receiver of a passive LocationUpdate via a PendingIntent.

The important part is to don't use the requestLocation update methods that take a listener object but use the [methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) that receive a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html). This way even if all your activities are finished at the moment a gps fix or network location is received the PendingIntent is fired and starts your service.
Reto Meier uses a Broadcast Receiver for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED that checks if the app should do location updates in the background and then requests the location updates with the PendingIntent.

Comment: perhaps i don't understand the principles of a passive location provider correctly. i was hoping this would get me amethod to register a passivelocationprovider and then wait passively until some other app retrieves a location update... right now i'm trying to do it this way: i have a remote service which again registers a passive location listener. unfortunately, onLocationChanged is never called :(

Comment: Read the blog post that is linked in my post everything is explained there. The problem with registering a listener object is that your app needs to stay active to enable the listener to work. I guess that your service is terminating itself after the listener is registered and then the listener is claimed by the java garbage collection. If you register a pending Intent the location manager will start your service at the moment a new location is available.

Answer (score 1):

The location manager does not broadcast the location updates. You have to request location updates programmatically.

Apart from that the receiver declaration in the manifest is for a `BroadcastReceiver`, your `LocationListener` is not a `BroadcastReceiver`. This means if someone would sent a braodcast matching your filter you would get a type mismatch when the class loader tries to instantiate the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: so there is no way to have some kind of "sleeping" application that does not run constantly in the background or so but has some functionality that is triggered every time a location fix is received?

Comment: You might consider using a background service, which requests location updates and then reacts in some useful ways to it. There is no need to have an activity open for that. But make sure that your device's CPU is not powered down when the user does not interact with the device by setting a WakeLock.

Comment: this is EXACTLY how i DONT want to do it! i want to listen for location updates i did NOT request by myself. to be more precise: each time, the user (or another application) activates gps and requests a location fix, i want my app to become active and react to this in some way. at other times, in want my app to keep passive - or better: completely inactive. so: a wake lock is not an option. a background service would probably do the trick, but this would require *some* effort for keeping it running etc etc etc...

Comment: is there any way to catch an intent telling me that the gps functionality has been activated? in this case i could listen for this intent to be broadcast and register a passive location listener in the broadcast receiver...

Comment: You can register a GpsStatusListener to receive an event if the GPS is activated. However, it has the same limitations as the location listener. Also you could use the AlarmManager to periodically check if the GPS is on and start a service which registers a LocationListener.

Answer (score 0):

Try registering a pending intent with the LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates() method:

```
LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent("Unique_Broadcast_Message");       
PendingIntent launchIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(your activity, 0, intent, 0);
mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, launchIntent);
```

Also, declare a receiver that receives "Unique_Broadcast_Message".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a library, then check this out. It uses passive location provider and provides it per Broadcast Receiver. Very easy to use.

[Little-Fluffy-Location Library for Android](https://code.google.com/p/little-fluffy-location-library/)